# Swift 3 GCD and Parse

Tags: swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

I'm beyond baffled how to accomplish this.

I want to call a function (func1) that will call func2 which does some Parse queries and submits them to the database.

Once all those queries have completed and func2 is completely finished running I want to run func3 which will do similar tasks.

I want to then update my tableView once func3 has completely finished running but I'm having no luck working with GCD.

My issue is when I call func1() then wait for the group to finish the tableview reload data function is executed before func3 is executed.

What would be the best way to solve this?

```
 let group = DispatchGroup()
 let queue1 = DispatchQueue()
 let queue2 = DispatchQueue() 
 let queue3 = DispatchQueue()

 func1(){
     queue1.async(group: group){
        for i in 0...10 {
            func2(i)
        }
     }

     group.notify(queue: queue2){
        func3()
     }
 }

 func2(i: Int){
      queue2.async(group: group){
           // Perform query for value i
           PFQuery.findObjectsInBackground {}
      }
 }


func3(){
     queue3.async(group: group){
        PFQuery.findObjectsInBackground {}
     }
}


func1()
group.notify(queue: queue4){
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

To simplify:

1. func1() calls func2() several times in a for loop.
2. all of the func2() calls must finish before func3() begins
3. func3() must finish before tableview can reload.

Comment: Which of these functions are async? What's the exact dependancies necessary for them to run? You should lay it all out in an (easy to follow) list.

Comment: I added a short list at the bottom of my post to simplify the dependencies.  The goal is to have all of them run async so that I can still update a label on main thread as to which function is executing currently.

Comment: The information provided in your list completely changes the question. I'll give it a stab

Comment: Also, you didn't specify which of those functions are asynchronous, which are synchronous.

Comment: I apologize. It's a complex situation I have a thousand lines of code or so written so I missed a few aspects when trying to abstract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you rather create a single method which is like composition for all asynchronous calculations. That makes it easy to have your control. And yes, you should call the notify after your last call only.

```
func func1(){
  queue1.async(group: group){
    print("Some work in background queue 1")
  }
}

func  func2(){
  queue2.async(group: group){
    print("Some work in background queue 2")
  }
}


func func3(){
  group.notify(queue: queue3) {
    print("Some work in background queue 3")
  }
}


func doCompositeOperations() {
  func1()
  func2()
  DispatchQueue.main.async(group: group) {
    print("Reloading after all")
  }

  func3()
}

doCompositeOperations()
```

I think func1, func2 func3 ... also perform some asynchronous operation in the queue of its own and returns the result in completion handler. I rather prefere enter and leave variant of dispatch group in cases like such where you can have finer control.

Comment: This needs some tweaks, it doesn't quite model the situation OP described

Comment: Not a bad solution but I need func2 to complete before func3 can begin to prevent duplicate data from occurring in my table view. So I do need to perform a notify on func2's group before func3 can begin. What would you suggest?

Comment: In that case you could call func 3 inside notify block for group and reloading table view would be queued after func 2 to the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first stab at this, given this information:

> - func1() calls func2() several times in a for loop.
> - all of the func2() calls must finish before func3() begins
> - func3() must finish before tableview can reload.

```
func1() {
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    for element in elements {
        group.enter()
        func2(element, completion: { group.leave() })
    }

    group.await()

    func3(completion: {tableview.reload() })
}
```

Comment: I'll try this now.

Comment: Got it working thanks everyone. Took bits and pieces from all solutions.

Comment: @mocode10 If your question has been resolved, please mark one of the answers as accepted. You have to understand that StackOverflow members aren't just here to answer your questions for you sake. The aim is to build a repository that allows future users to find answers to their questions. Your question is broad, unclear, poorly abstracted, and of very little use to anyone but yourself. I strongly suggest you edit it into something more tangible.

Answer (score -1):

```
func func1() {

    // Call func 2 and give it a block of work to execute when it is done
    func2(completionHandler: {
        // call func3 and give it a block of work to do when it is done
        func3(completionHandler: {
            // call back to the main thread to update the table
            update_my_table()
        }
    })
}

func func2(completionHandler: () -> void) {
    PFQuery.findObjectsInBackground()

    ... other work that must be done before func3 ...

    // execute work that should be done when func2 completes
    completionHandler()
}

func func3(completionHandler: () -> void) {
    ... do some stuff to prepare table data ...

    // execute work that must be done when func 3 completes
    completionHandler()
}

func update_my_table() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Completion handlers get really messy (even in this simple mechanism). It's better to stick with queues and groups.

Comment: I'll have to learn up on completion handlers. I'm not too familiar with them.  So they would execute after the findObjectsInBackground has completely finished even though that method is an asynchronous call?

Comment: A completion handler is not magic.  It is simply a block that you call when a function completes its work. I would have to know more about `PFQuery` to answer that question.  If `findObjectsInBackground` is a synchronous call then func2 will not move on to call it's completion handler until that function is finished.

Comment: Looking at the parse documentation it looks like you could replace `findObjectsInBackground` with `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` which is a `Parse` function that does the query AND lets you provide a completion handler.  Might just replace `func2` with that

Comment: It's an asynchronous call.  Because of that, would the completion handler not be a viable solution?

Comment: @ScottThompson Just look at it. You have a chain of only 3 functions, and you've already nested in 2 levels. What happens when you need to run a more realistic series of steps (for example, 10), one after another? Are you going to nest 9 levels in?

Comment: I'll give the findObjectsInBGWithBlock option a try. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If I had a chain of 10, it is likely I would use a different solution.  Even in this case it is unlikely that I would use inline blocks.  But this is abstract code, not production.